# MS Access query to ORDER BY date from C++ application

Tags: c++, sql, ms-access

How does a MS Access SQL query for ordering by date looks like? My current query is:

```
newVal.Format(_T("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (CDATE(DateStart) BETWEEN #%s# AND #%s#) "), strDateVal, strDateVal2);
```

where `strDateVal` and `strDateVal2` are CStrings resulting from formating ColeDateTime variables. In this form i get all the dates between `strDateVal` and `strDateVal2` (eg. 10/20/2013 and 10/25/2013), but i can't figure out a way to sort it, ascending or descending.
I've tried using

```
ORDER BY DateStart ASC
ORDER BY=([DateStart] ASC)
ORDER BY (CDATE(DateStart)) ASC
```

but none worked, i get an empty result.

Comment: So are you saying that your current query (with no ORDER BY) returns results, but if you add an `ORDER BY DateStart` clause to the end of it you get no errors but you also get no results?

Comment: With the first querry i get results, but after adding an ORDER BY, the recordset has no records.

Comment: Do you have a `try/catch` that might be suppressing errors? FWIW, I just tried `SELECT * FROM Table ...` and it failed with "syntax error in FROM clause". I had to change it to `SELECT * FROM [Table] ...`. Once I fixed that I got results both with and without `ORDER BY DateStart`.

Comment: I have a `try/catch block`, but i debugged the code all the way and there is no error thrown. And for me, using the plain `Table` works, as well as using field names the same way, with no enclosure in []. How does the SQL query you are using looks like? So i can give it a shot.

Comment: I tried using the same format for my query, but it's not working. Thx anyway!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope another C++ user can help you out with this.

Comment: is your query with order by like this? `"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (CDATE(DateStart) BETWEEN #%s# AND #%s#) ORDER BY DateStart ASC"`

Comment: @mucio tried that one too, no result. Something's funny here, ordering by TEXT or NUMBER type works, but when it comes to DATE type i quess is somehow trickier.

Comment: if you run the query in access with the order by does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, and it was quite simple and silly: the correct sintax is `ORDER BY Table.Field ASC`. So you have to use the table name even if you make a simple `SELECT`, as if you would make a `JOIN`.